# Java Jackson JSON without POJOs

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

I am currently converting a node project to DW. The node project currently stores JSON from the client as a string and then returns application/JSON when the client gets the same resource.  This is basically a Key/value store reset endpoint.

I want to implement the same with dropwizard, but I do not want to map out the entire structure and it's nested structures in POJOs.  Is there a way to allow for this? I just want to save the JSON as a string in the db with the key, I do not want to work with the data at all in the java application.

Since the APIs require that I return an object, what should the object be?  Here is the function I have for DW, as you can see it is expecting to return an object.

```
@GET
@UnitOfWork
@Timed
@ApiOperation(value="Find value by ID", notes="Get a value object from the DAO using ID as the sole criterion")
@ApiResponses(value={
        @ApiResponse(code=400, message="Invalid ID"),
        @ApiResponse(code=404, message="No object found by specified ID")
})
public SomeJavaOjbectMustGoHere getSample(
            @ApiParam(value="id of object to get", required=true)
            @QueryParam("id")
            Long id
        ) throws WebApplicationException {

    SomeJavaOjbectMustGoHere returned = dao.get(id);
    if (returned == null) throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    else return returned;
}
```

Here is most of the code from node:

```js
module.exports = function (server) {

  function createResponse(req, res, next) {

   var key = req.params.name;
   console.log("Creating Response for key: '" + req.params.name + "'");

    // ...some validation...
    if (..blah..) { 
      // fail out.
      res.send(403, "response can not be saved without a valid key and structure.");
      return next();
    }

    
    var data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    // ... store the stuff in the db...

    res.send(201, "Saved");
    return next();
  }

  function getResponse(req, res, next) {
    try {
      var payload = {};
      
      // ... get the data matching the key...

      res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.send(200, JSON.parse(payload.toString()));
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log('Data not found.' + err);
      res.send(200,
        {
          "id": Math.random().toString(36).substr(3, 8),
          // ... default structure ...
        });
    }
    return next();
  }

  function send(req, res, next) {
    res.send('response ' + req.params.name);
    return next();
  }

  server.post('/response/:name', createResponse);
  server.put('/response', send);
  server.get('/response/:name', getResponse);
  server.head('/response/:name', send);
  server.del('/response/:name', function rm(req, res, next) {
    res.send(204);
    return next();
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create your own Object model then Jackson has a [JsonNode class](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html).

If you don't want to do anything with the data you could just return a `String` and add the following annotation to your method:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: Thanks, looking in to it now.  Would I need to change the post also? How would I get the string, is it just body?

Comment: Yes. You can accept the post body as a String as well

Comment: All sites telling about JsonNode advice to use it for translation json into POJO. So, it does not see a good example.